# OpenID Connect security considerations in ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, client, openid-connect

I'm looking at `OpenIdConnectHandler` https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs used as authentication handler in ASP NET Core and there I see some
strange (as for me) practices.

Firstly, it looks that state it's just bytes of encrypted `AuthenticationProperties` (line 252). Furthermore, CorrelationId (probably the equivalent of state) is generated before
(another?) state is setted and the correlation id value is 'N'. It doesn't make sense for me.

Secondly, cookie with nonce also has value equals to 'N'.

Why are these values ​​in the cookie name instead of in its value? And what is the state parameter in the future authorization redirection? After all, they can't be bytes from the encrypted AuthenticationProperties, I think they are not cryptographically random.
I completely don't understand this code, how does it actually work?

Answer (score 0):

The state parameter lets the client(handler) set a custom data container and pass it in the initial authentication request as a state parameter.

Then the client will receive this state data along with the authorization code.

The client should verify that the state sent matches the received state. The state can here be used to pass some custom "state" that the client wants to remember during the authentication phase.

The PKCE flow visualized:

[image]

I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:

- [Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: So state isn't cryptographically random bytes? It also can be as here bytes of encrypted AuthenticationProperties? And why state is saved in cookie name instead of cookie value?

Comment: As far as I know, the state can be anything, something that the client can use to validate that the returned authorization code came from a request the client initially created. State is similar to PKCE, but the other way around; PKCE is validated on the server. While state is validated on the client.

Comment: Ok, so it seems to be safe. But I forgot to mention that AuthenticationProperties contains code_verifier. Isn't it security violation?

Comment: No, the Code_verifier together with the code_challenge is part of the PKCE security add-on, and it is safe to pass in the request.

Comment: `code_verifier` is used to request the token, `code_challenge` is used to request the `authorization_code`, and then the user's authorization is performed, right? This should be the start of the authorization process, so it can pass the request safely.

Comment: code_verifier and code_challenge are part of PKCE and you can do OpenID-Connect fine without it, but PKCE gives you an additional layer of security in the authorization service supports it.  You include the code_challenge as part of the initial authentication request and then the code_verifier when you later ask for the actual token. Added picture that I made to my answer about the PKCE flow.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. But as we can see at line 402: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs#L402 they add code_verifier to AuthenticationProperties and then at line 459 they set `state` parameter for authorization request to protected AuthorizationProperties. Yes, the same properties that contains code_verifier. So protected code_verifier is sent with authorization request, if I understand well this code.

Comment: I guess they store the code_verifier encrypted inside the state, as as way to remember what initial code_verifier that was used, so that it can pass it later to the provider when it needs to get the code.  It needs to somehow rememer the verifier.